# How to draw a linear chord diagram

Tags: plot, data-visualization, chord-diagram

Is there any software or library able to produce a chord diagram like this one (not in circular form)?[image]

Answer (score 1):

While searching for the name of those "linear chord diagrams" i stumbled over this question.

There are probably differences, but those things are called sankey diagrams.

To answer your question (even though it's pretty old):
https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/ supports different types of sankey diagrams.

I just wanted to note, that these are called sankey diagrams for anyone else searching for the name.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Do not answer off topic questions. [answer] Instead, vote to close them.

Comment: And yet this led me to the d3 library version of sankey diagrams. Maybe there can be a stackunderflow site to catch all these useful answers mods hate but the public still needs.